# LED brightness control using rotary encoder

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I want to make a circuit where I have to use a rotary encoder to control the brightness of LEDS. I managed to get a single LED to work, but when trying to connect 6 more LEDs I can't seem to get it to work.

My setup basic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVdh3.jpg *(as the note says, I have a 5 pin Encoder, only a six pin was available)*

```
int Brightness = 120;
int StepBrightness = 10;
unsigned long RealTime;
unsigned long CyclicTime;
const int pin_A = 2;  // pin 2 de CLK aansluiting van de Rotary encoder
const int pin_B = 3;  // pin 3 De DT aansluiting van de Rotary encoder
unsigned char encoder_A;
unsigned char encoder_B;
unsigned char encoder_A_vorige=0;

void setup()  {
  pinMode(9, OUTPUT); //I can only get pin 9 and no other pins work if I put different digit
  pinMode(pin_A, INPUT);
  pinMode(pin_B, INPUT);
  RealTime = millis();
  CyclicTime = RealTime; 
} 

void loop()  {
  RealTime = millis();
  if(RealTime >= (CyclicTime + 5)){
    encoder_A = digitalRead(pin_A);
    encoder_B = digitalRead(pin_B);   
    if((!encoder_A) && (encoder_A_vorige)){
      if(encoder_B) {
        if(Brightness + StepBrightness <= 255) Brightness += StepBrightness;               
      }   
      else {
        if(Brightness - StepBrightness >= 0) Brightness -= StepBrightness;               
      }   

    }   
    encoder_A_vorige = encoder_A;

    analogWrite(9, Brightness);   
   
    CyclicTime = RealTime;
  }
                           
}
```

Comment: there is no attempt to analogWrite 6 LEDs in the sketch in your question

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare output pins and write to them using analog write which is now set to turn a single (9) pin and not a variable (the pin you would want to turn at that point).

Answer (score 0):

For Arduino Uno, only the following pins have PWM -> **3, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11**

Therefore, only these few pins will work with the `analogWrite()` function and the other pins are not.

You do not need to call `pinMode()` to set the pin as an output before calling `analogWrite()`.